# javascript - check if div is visible when setting visibility with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility, visible

In my html I have one div that is set to be invisible

```
 <div id ="isticContainer" style='display:none'>
```

Then I have one radio button, and when the radio button is checked/clicked my div appears

```
$('#viem').click(function() { 


$('#isticContainer').show();
 }
```

Now, I want to check if that div is hidden or not and if it is visible I want another div appear:

```
 if($('#isticContainer').is(':visible')) {
    $('#bonusy7').fadeIn();
 }
```

Unfortunately this isnt working. I assume, that is because i have set it to hidden in my html. How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Where is your condition, what is the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if($('#isticContainer').css('display') != 'none' ) {
     $('#bonusy7').fadeIn();
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, doesnt work, because in my html I have set display:none. It is still there even if js shows that div. So when js checked through html and finds display:none, it wont show it

Comment: Try removing the inline css (display:none;) of the html element, and add hide it by jquery at the beggining of your script with `$('#isticContainer').hide();` and see if it works then.

Comment: That was, what I did at first, but I have also other hidden divs, which I am showing/hiding through the "lifecycle" of my web app and this caused that the other divs could not show like I want them.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is #bonusy7 to fade in after #isticContainer is shown, then you could always just link them with the show()'s on complete function.

```
$('#isticContainer').show(function () {
   $('#bonusy7').fadeIn();
});
```